# How can I fix this error "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"?

Tags: r

I am writing a function to find a date x months back form a current date. I keep getting an error/warning.

```
DateBack <- function(CurrentYear, CurrentMonth, MonthsBack){
if(MonthsBack< 13){
    if(MonthsBack>=CurrentMonth){
        month<-12+CurrentMonth-MonthsBack
        datet<-paste(CurrentYear-1,month, sep="-")
    } 
    else{
        month<-CurrentMonth-MonthsBack
        datet<-paste(CurrentYear-1, month, sep="-")
    }
} 
else{
    Years <- trunc(MonthsBack/12,0)
    if((MonthsBack-12*Years)>=CurrentMonth){
        month<-12+CurrentMonth-MonthsBack
    } 
    else{
        month<-CurrentMonth-MonthsBack
    }
    datet<-paste(CurrentYear-Years, month, sep="-")
}
return(datet)
}

CurrentYear<- c(2000, 2000, 2003, 2004)
CurrentMonth<-c(1, 2, 6, 12) 

df<- data.frame(CurrentYear, CurrentMonth)

df$MonthsBack <- DateBack(df$CurrentYear,df$CurrentMonth,1)
```

Warning message:
In if (MonthsBack >= CurrentMonth) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

How would I go about correcting this error?

Comment: The message means that one or both of `MonthsBack` and `CurrentMonth` are vectors. Only the first element of each vector is used to test the "if" condition.  But your **real** problem is trying to invent your own datetime function when there are solid, proven tools in place.  Skim thedailywtf.com for a zillion examples of homebrewed date-time functions gone bad.

Comment: you can solve your problem by using `all` or `any`. For example: `if(any(MonthsBack>=CurrentMonth))`. Otherwise, I second completely @CarlWitthoft comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second CarlWitthoft comment too, although there does not seem to be an easy answer through date functions.

The issue in the code is the conditional statement which is not vectorized.  You can implement it with no IF statement in a fully vectorized manner:

```
DateBack = function (Y,M, monthsBack) {
   YM = (Y*12 + M - 1) - monthsBack
   newY = YM %/% 12
   newM = YM %% 12 + 1
   return( paste( newY, newM, sep="-"))
 }

DateBack( c(2000,2000,2003,2004),c(1,2,6,12),1)
[1] "1999-12" "2000-1"  "2003-5"  "2004-11"
```

Comment: Not easy?  Pseudocode: 1)extract 'month' value from a POSIXct date.  2) Subtract `x` from that value.  3) subtract that POSIXct month value from the original date string.